# Does the last delivery still count when a match is resumed after an interruption?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating

In a limited overs match, the scores were tied after the end of the "regular" overs, so a Super Over was being played to decide the winner. Both teams had agreed to resume the match the next day if it was interrupted due to rain, bad light or similar. The third ball of the Super Over was a full toss which was edged and caught cleanly. The square leg umpire did not call a no ball.

The batsmen asked the square leg umpire if it was a no ball, but the umpire stated that he was not able to see the ball. The batsmen continued to argue with the umpire until the match was eventually called off due to bad light.

Does the third ball, and the wicket, count when the match is resumed?

Comment: Edited for readability - this a good laws question.

Comment: Why would it not count? The law does not say that a ball is counted only when the batsman finishes arguing with the umpire.

Answer (score 3):

The third ball was completed, so it counts. There is nothing in [Law 3](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-3-the-umpires/), in particular Section 9, "Suspension of play in dangerous or unreasonable conditions" which even hints at the idea that a ball might not count if runs are scored or a wicket falls.

More generally, I'm concerned that you're letting your players run the game, rather than the umpires. There is absolutely no way that players should be arguing with umpires over whether a ball was a no ball or not - that is solely for the umpires to decide, and players should accept the decision. Doing anything else is dissent.